# Why don't suggested Edits show the output?

Tags: feature-request, status-norepro, suggested-edits

So I've thought a few times when reviewing Suggested Edits it would be really useful to see how the question/answer actually looks before/after in the same way when you actually edit a post you can see the output below.

I think it can sometimes be quite difficult to spot the change (I.e. when they've just added ` around some code) or to tell how changed indentation or splitting lines looks

Is this a possibility?

I did a search for similar posts with suggested edits in the title but I don't know if there is a way to actually see what features are currently suggested/being implemented so apologies if this is duplicate

Comment: You mean the [rendered output] and [markdown] buttons?

Comment: I had literally never noticed them before. Now I feel stupid.

Comment: It would still be nice if there was a way to hide the green highlighting (which hides the grey from \`)

Comment: Also nice, a way to force showing it all, even if it's huge swathes of "nothing changed"...

Comment: @Deduplicator, Nick — please feel free to make other feature requests regarding those other changes you suggested so they can be more visible than a comment!